# Java getDeclaredMethod() parameterTypes for string parameter

Tags: java, string

I have a simple question. I want to get `String.TYPE` as `parameterType` in `getDeclaredMethod()` but I can not find it.There is for example `Long.TYPE` for Long data type but there is not any thing similar for String type. 
Can some one help me about this?
thanks

```
Object newClass;
newClass = Class.forName(cls.getName()).getConstructor().newInstance();
           for (Method m : cls.getClass().getMethods())
                if (m.getName().startsWith("get") && m.getParameterTypes().length == 0) {
                    try {
                        //final Object r = m.invoke(cls);
                        String MethodName=m.getName().replace("get","");

                        if (m.getReturnType().equals(Long.TYPE)){
                        //    Class<?> c = Class.forName("class name");

                        }else
                        {
                            String value =this.getString(j,MethodName);
                            Method  method = cls.getDeclaredMethod (MethodName, String);//Here I need Parameter Type for string imput parameter
                            method.invoke (newClass, value);
                        }


                    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    // do your thing with r
                }
```

Comment: I will suggest use .class that will work. You don't have to go in .TYPE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this one. It works fine.

```
Test obj = new Test();
        for (Method m : obj.getClass().getDeclaredMethods()){
            if (m.getName().startsWith("get") && m.getParameterTypes().length == 1) {
                System.out.println("==="+m.getName());
                if (m.getReturnType().equals(String.class)) {
                    String value = "ABCD";
                    Method  method = Test.class.getDeclaredMethod (m.getName(), String.class);
                    method.invoke (obj, value);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

`Long.TYPE` is for the primitive type `long`.

There is no such thing for reference types such as String.

You want `String.class`. (`Long.class` would be for the boxed type `Long`).

Answer (score 1):

How about using `String.class` ??